# Sharepoint List Connector constrained by LVT?

Tags: list-view, excel

It is possible to access SharePoint View Data in Excel using the MS SharePoint connector, using code such as

```
<LIST><VIEWGUID>{A75A8452-A561-4CFB-92B1-9D02E292320C}</VIEWGUID><LISTNAME>{EAAAA340-01EF-40B6-8AB7-8BD5DF076947}</LISTNAME><LISTWEB>http://<path to list>//_vti_bin</LISTWEB><LISTSUBWEB></LISTSUBWEB><ROOTFOLDER>/sites/germany/coll/wup/IT/Lists/Dell Bestellungen</ROOTFOLDER></LIST>
```

(e.g. https://community.qlik.com/thread/57573)

Can anyone advise whether such connectors are subject to LVT constraints?

Thanks!